# Is there a single word for " the first thing to consider is"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or idiom for " the first thing to consider is"?

Comment: How about "Firstly"?

Comment: @Ste How does that differ from 'First'?

Comment: *First*, no. or yes. But not *Firstly*. And it will not be defined as indicating primary criteria.

Comment: @SrJoven 'First' and 'Firstly' are both acceptable as pragmatic [discourse structuring] markers ("Practical English Usage" p 141; [Michael Swan](http://rouabhiateacher.weebly.com/uploads/1/5/9/3/15936890/discourse_markers.pdf)

Comment: @SrJoven You're correct that this is discourse-structuring rather than highlighting/focusing. 'First and foremost' (this time _not_ 'firstly') is needed to fulfil both roles.

Comment: Is there an idiom for an idiom? Yes. There's your answer. Is there a single word for "the first thing to consider?" No. There's your answer. Please pick a question that can be answered in other than "yes" or "no."

Answer (score 3):

I think [priority](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Priority) may fit: (from TFD)

> - Precedence, especially established by order of importance or urgency.
> - A preceding or coming earlier in time.
> - Something afforded or deserving prior attention.

or the expression: 
'*[at the top of the list](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/at+the+top+of+the+list.html)*':

> - If something is at the top of the list, it is of highest priority, most important, most urgent, or the next in one's line of attention.

*First off* and *first of all* are other common expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping for some sorts of adv like "firstly " as mentioned .

Answer (score 3):

A rather unusual (importance-)emphasising pragmatic marker is **imperatively**.

> Imperatively, we MUST peel off probable Republican votes.

(Dennis Macek speaking to ‎Dave Domina) on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/votedomina/posts/511546655615542)

*Most importantly* is rather more common, but I think that 'importantly' on its own is a rather rare pragmatic usage.

Comment: Neither of these describe order, only importance. Important things don't necessarily come first.

Comment: @talmu Ah, you've missed this sense for _first_: foremost in position, rank, or importance.
"the doctor's first duty is to respect this right" [Google Dictionary]. This is an acceptable reading of 'The first thing we must consider is ... / The first thing to consider is ...'. 'First' or 'Firstly' is the structuring marker – either way, your question is not a good one.

Comment: I suppose this is something the asker needs to clarify. To my knowledge, the phrase given in the question more often prioritizes position over importance, but I can see how it might be used in the way you're describing.

Comment: OP did subsequently clarify. A look at the answers given before that shows that both senses of 'first' were assumed by different responders. It's difficult to judge which sense is prevailing in most of the Google returns for a "the first thing to consider is" search, but there seem to be ten times as many hits as there are for "the second thing to consider is". Obviously, with 'the first thing to cook is', the sequencing sense is almost mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom *front burner* or *[to be on the front burner](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-on-the-front-burner#to-be-on-the-front-burner_1)* means

> to be of the hiɡhest priority: *It helps to put an important issue back on the front burner. It's on my front burner.*

[*Collins*]

Comment: I've only ever heard *on the back burner*, which suggests the opposite. I only understand *on the front burner* because I know of the former idiom. Just an observation.

Comment: @talrnu It's out there. See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=front+burner&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfront%20burner%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Adv : **Primarily**, means 
[in the beginning](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/primarily)

Comment: *Primarily* describes importance or significance, not order. The last in a list of things to consider could still be of primary importance.

Answer (score 0):

**Topmost** fits the description in the question. Another word may be **foremost**.

[**Topmost**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/topmost) (Collins Dictionary) The topmost thing in a number of things is the one that is highest or nearest the top. ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/topmost)) Highest.

[**Foremost**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foremost) (Collins Dictionary) The foremost thing or person in a group is the most important or best.